# Project planning software for Linux

Tags: linux, project-management

I am looking for a project planning software for Linux which supports the following features:

- define a task A *x* days before or after a given task B
- if the date of task B changes also the date of A changes correspondingly
- show the date of task A
- provide a Gantt diagram

Nice to have:

- visualize the dependence between A and B
- export list dates of tasks as a list for printing

Comment: [*ProjectLibre*](http://www.projectlibre.com/product/projectlibre-open-source) perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Try [GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/)

It simple, but look like it meet requirements.

I don't sure only about  "timeline view" (Gantt diagram not it?) and "export list dates of tasks as a list for printing".

**UPD**

For example,

- make task B depend on A
- in B properties set delay (positive or negative)  to shift start of task B relative to end of task A
- change start date for task A, and task B change dates automatically.

Or I misunderstood what's You mean by 1 and 2

**UPD2**
[image: Screnshot illustration]

Comment: I tried it but didn't see how to get point 1 and 2 of my requirements.

Comment: Did you make sure that A and B have a "finish to start" relationship?  Not sure about starting X days after, though - you might have to defined a dummy X day project between them

Comment: Im tried again on my GanttProject 2.7.1 Ostrava (build 1924)
I can define finish to start relationship (on task B) relative to Task A and set Delay. When I changed date of task A, task B moved.